# use docusign api creates envelopes, error: Object moved

Tags: java, docusignapi

I consulted the API documentation and sent it successfully in api explorer-> Envelopes: create. I also got json & request path & token. I used httpclient post in java and received Object moved Object moved to here . Does anyone know what I missed?
      `

```
    DocsignDocument docsignDocument = new DocsignDocument();
    docsignDocument.setDocumentBase64
    docsignDocument.setDocumentId("1");
    docsignDocument.setFileExtension("pdf");
    docsignDocument.setName("Test.pdf");
    list.add(docsignDocument);
    Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
    Signers signers = new Signers();
    signers.setEmail("xxxx");
    signers.setName("Qin");
    signers.setRecipientId("1");
    Signers signers1 = new Signers();
    signers1.setEmail("xxx@qq.com");
    signers1.setName("OYX");
    signers1.setRecipientId("2");
    List<Signers> signersList = new ArrayList<>();
    signersList.add(signers);
    signersList.add(signers1);
    recipients.setSigners(signersList);
    dataJson.put("documents",list);
    dataJson.put("emailSubject","TEST");
    dataJson.put("recipients",recipients);
    dataJson.put("status","sent");
    String data = dataJson.toJSONString();
    String results2 = HttpDocusignUtils.httpPostJson("https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxx/envelopes",access_token,data)`
```

post request：

```
 public static String httpPostJson(String uri, String token, String obj) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); // 添加请求头
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
       httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch");
       httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj));
        System.out.println(httpPost);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instreams = entity.getContent();
            result = convertStreamToString(instreams);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxx/envelopes` is not a valid DocuSign endpoint.

The Account Server (account-d.docusign.com) is used to get a token and make a [UserInfo](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints) call to determine the correct base URL for a particular account.

Because you're in the Demo environment, your base url will begin with `https://demo.docusign.net`

Comment: Thank you Drew, yes, send the envelopes using the domain name: https://demo.docusign.net, everything is working fine so far

Comment: Good to hear. In the Production Environment, there are several possible server environments, so be sure you have a method ready to go once you're live.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one issue is that the the Document model in Java is `Document` from

`import com.docusign.esign.model.Document;`

To debug, I suggest using the [DocuSign API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) feature. Then update (**edit**) your question to include the JSON shown in the log.

Were you able to run the code examples for Java? See [eg-03-java-auth-code-grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant)

Also, please tell us (by editing your question) what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I used: https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant
But I can't run, so I tested from: https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/, and succeeded, so I use REST request according to the request example

Answer (score 0):

**Creates envelopes - Use Base Url in Api Call**

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/
```

**Error Reason is use Wrong url** - `https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2.1/accounts/`

[DocuSign Developers Documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/)